# How do I zoom/pan on enlarged canvas using d3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have my canvas zoom/pan by using d3 and it works fine.
But here comes my problem. I need to zoom on and enlarge an image inside
the canvas.
Since the image is too small and to fit it inside the parent div without changing the canvas actual width and height I set the `canvas.style.width` to 90% in order for the canvas to fill the 90% of the parent div.
But when zoom is made, the zoom is not OK. Can you please tell me what should I do to fix this issue?

What should I set on the d3 side after setting the 90% width on the canvas style?

```js
var imgCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var imgCtx = imgCanvas.getContext('2d');
var d3Zoom = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 3]).on("zoom", zoom),
 d3Canvas  = d3.select("canvas").call(d3Zoom).on("dblclick.zoom", null),
 d3Ctx     = d3Canvas.node().getContext("2d"),
 d3width   = d3Canvas.property("width"),
 d3height  = d3Canvas.property("height");
var img = new Image();

function zoom() {
var transform = d3.event.transform;
d3Ctx.save();
imgCtx.clearRect(0, 0, imgCanvas.width, imgCanvas.height),
d3Ctx.clearRect(0, 0, d3width, d3height);
d3Ctx.translate(transform.x, transform.y);
d3Ctx.scale(transform.k, transform.k);
d3Ctx.beginPath();
d3Ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
d3Ctx.fill();
d3Ctx.restore();
}

window.onload=function() {
img.src = 
 "https://www.bullionstar.com/files/"
 + "gold-coins/100_100_gold-coin-canada-maple-leaf-2017-1oz-back.jpg";
img.onload = function() {
 
 imgCanvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
 imgCanvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
 imgCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imgCanvas.width, imgCanvas.height);
 imgCanvas.style.height = "90%";
}
};
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div width ="500px" height ="500px">
<div width ="100%" height ="500px">
 <div width ="100%" height ="100%">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you mean setting the canvas height doesn't work ?

first, div has no width/height attributes ( set via style/css instead )

second, you should change your xform to

```
d3Ctx.scale( imgCanvas.width/imgCanvas.clientWidth,imgCanvas.height/imgCanvas.clientHeight);
d3Ctx.translate(transform.x, transform.y);
d3Ctx.scale(transform.k, transform.k);
d3Ctx.scale( imgCanvas.clientWidth/imgCanvas.width, imgCanvas.clientHeight/imgCanvas.height);
```

where the two scalings ( one the inverse of the other ) map the zoom xform to client canvas coordinates...